# How to include '-' in the string with regex check

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the below regex, which currently allows '_' but not '-'.

```
string validCharacters = @"^\w+$";

Regex.Match(componentName, validCharacters);
```

But I want to also to include '-' as a valid character. The '-' can be at any place in the string. i,e: first,last,middle,after '_' etc.

Below are the few test cases:

**"DTD_rtop-234"**

**"DTD-rtop_234"**

**"-DTD_rtop-234"**

**"DTD_rtop-234-"**

**"DTD_-rtop-234"**

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What you mean under _"does not allow '_'"_?

Comment: @SeM It means it allows [underscore] but not [hypen].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the `-` character with the `\w` characters in a single character class:
`[-\w]`.

Your desired regex is therefore:
`^[-\w]+$`.

Comment: Perfect ! Clean, clear and brief

Comment: Use this solution and check on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks @Samantha . It's solved my purpose.